# ALSA: how to temporarily change the output device

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I want to do a simplest thing possible in ALSA: to have USB-headphones produce sound instead of internal speaker of my tablet. I don't want to change config files such as `asound.rc` or `alsa.conf` or `asound.conf` and permanently set headphones as default output device by changing the order of devices, I want a temporary effect, just until I unplug the headphones. Strangely, I can't google the answer. Is `alsamixer` capable of doing that (seems like no)?

In Gnome you can easily select current output device with `PulseAudio`, either in its GUI or CLI interface, but `PulseAudio` itself works on top of ALSA! So I also wonder, how it forces ALSA to change the output device?

Comment: `alsamixer` does have a "Select sound card" option in the interface, although I don't know if that also actually sets the output device.

Comment: no, unfortunately it just displays the parameters of this sound card and allows to tweak them, but doesn't redirect output to it

Comment: Hello, you can try exec `alsamixer` from a terminal and press `F6` for select another sound card. :)

Comment: @sgmart Hi, sgmart, i did exactly that, but it doesn't transfer sound to that device, it just selects that device for tuning its parameters, not streams output to it.

Comment: The alsamixer utility has some controls: Master, PCI, and so on. Check if there is a `MM` label (MM = mute), so use the `M` key from your keyboard to enable the sound.

Comment: @sgmart That really worked, thank you! Do I get it right, that devices listed by `alsamixer` are not the actual hardware devices, but ALSA devices, created by alsa plugins in `/usr/share/alsa`? I do mostly understand the syntax of those plugins in alsa.conf, but can't find the definitions of some very basic keywords, such as "pcm" or "ctl" or "type". I failed to find any list of keywords in the doxygen documentation: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/, http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/conf.html. Do you know of any source of info about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the USB device is listed as a sound card in the system, you may want to check `man amixer` and use the `unmute` parameter.

```
amixer -c 1 set Master playback 100% unmute
```

Check also the other channels (PCM etc.). The examples from the manual are:

```
   amixer -c 1 sset Line,0 80%,40% unmute cap
          will set the second soundcard's left line input volume to 80% and right line
          input to 40%, unmute it, and select it as a source for capture (recording).

   amixer -c 1 -- sset Master playback -20dB
          will set the master volume of the second card to -20dB.  If the  master  has
          multiple channels, all channels are set to the same value.

   amixer -c 1 set PCM 2dB+
          will  increase  the PCM volume of the second card with 2dB.  When both play‐
          back and capture volumes exist, this is applied to both volumes.

   amixer -c 2 cset iface=MIXER,name='Line Playback Volume",index=1 40%
          will set the third soundcard's second line playback volume(s) to 40%

   amixer -c 2 cset numid=34 40%
          will set the 34th soundcard element to 40%
```

Comment: Thanks, Jari, it works. I've been reading the manuals on ALSA and have a question: are the devices listed by amixer and alsamixer actually not hardware devices, but ALSA devices, created by alsa plugins in /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf and friends? I do mostly understand the syntax of those plugins, but can't find the definitions of the very fundamental keywords, such as "pcm" or "ctl" or "type". I failed to find any list of keywords in the doxygen documentation: alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib, alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/conf.html. Do you know of any source of info about them?

Comment: This doesn't really solve the original question.  You can set the parameters, but it does not change the card through which audio is outputed.

Comment: I agree with @oneself. This doesn't change the output device on-the-fly/temporarily.

Comment: If this actually answers the original question, a full example is needed. How does this do anything that alsamixer can't do? Clearly, alsamixer can't switch to output through a different sound card. Or, in my case, I also wanted to output through the same sound card but HDMI instead of speakers/headphone. Pulseaudio does these things, but how? Examples from start to finish are needed to make this a good answer.

Comment: For controlling a card's devices, use the `-d` option. E.g. if I have a soundcard with 3,5mm jack and HDMI audio, controlling the HDMI can be done with `amixer -c 0 -d 1 set Master mute` for instance.

Comment: Pitty this has been selected as answer - the question is _exactly_ what I'm looking for: how to temporarily change the card used for output. However, as @oneself already noted, this answer does not actually explain how to do that. Asking a new question with almost the same title is now likely to get closed as duplicate.

Comment: @domsson just link back to this one and explain that the answer didn't solve your issue. That should ensure it isn't closed as a dupe.

Comment: If someone is looking for HDMI audio solution here's good one: http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.com/2014/02/howto-switch-to-hdmi-audio-out.html

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can update `.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf` dynamically.  So it should be possible to have two files `headphones.conf` and `front.conf` which set your default devices to the appropriate `hw:channel,device` numbers and then switch them on an "ACPI jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" event.  I'm about to try this, using "ln" to link `/etc/asound.conf` to one of `/etc/sounds/{headphones,front}.conf`

Comment: It doesn't work until you restart the software that uses audio.

Answer (score 0):

Many sound applications can use other, non-default outputs. Even Chromium browser has command line switch to choose sound output. You can create a simple wrapper to run your sound application with desired output to avoid messing with conf every time.

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for this, and it does not seem that alsamixer can do this.  A slightly tangential approach is to launch pavucontrol, which easily allows for this. pavucontrol can be launched from terminal and if you go to playback, you can easily switch b/w the available outputs.